# Hazelcast distributed query using indexes

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to query Hazelcast map using predicates. My predicate code works fine without indexes but for better performance, I want to put index on the `key` my Hazelcast map.

Map Structure: `IMap<Event, Long>` - `Event` is a POJO class.

```
<map name="event.map">
  <in-memory-format>NATIVE</in-memory-format>
  <backup-count>2</backup-count>
  <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
  <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds>
  <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
  <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy>
  <max-size policy="FREE_NATIVE_MEMORY_PERCENTAGE">25</max-size>
  <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>
  <indexes>
    <index ordered="true">eventType</index>
</indexes>
</map>
```

With the above Map config, I get following exception:

```
Jul 19, 2019 10:04:21 PM com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDEntryOperation
SEVERE: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'eventType' on class 'java.lang.Long'
com.hazelcast.query.QueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'eventType' on class 'java.lang.Long'
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:175)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.instantiateGetter(Extractors.java:124)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.getGetter(Extractors.java:101)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.extract(Extractors.java:63)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValueFromTargetObject(QueryableEntry.java:144)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:82)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:48)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getConverter(QueryableEntry.java:67)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.IndexImpl.saveEntryIndex(IndexImpl.java:79)
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.Indexes.saveEntryIndex(Indexes.java:164)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractRecordStore.saveIndex(AbstractRecordStore.java:165)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.putInternal(DefaultRecordStore.java:709)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.setWithUncountedAccess(DefaultRecordStore.java:987)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.onAddedOrUpdated(EntryOperator.java:288)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.doPostOperateOps(EntryOperator.java:219)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDEntryOperation.runVanilla(HDEntryOperation.java:257)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDEntryOperation.runInternal(HDEntryOperation.java:95)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDMapOperation.run(HDMapOperation.java:88)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:208)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:197)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:407)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:434)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:586)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:571)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:530)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:220)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:60)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:67)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.doRun(AbstractMessageTask.java:111)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:101)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:161)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:159)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:127)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'eventType' on class 'java.lang.Long'
        at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:168)
        ... 35 more
```

From the exception I understand that Hazelcast is trying to apply the index on the `Value` field of the `IMap`.

Is there a way index can be put on the `Key` field of the `IMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
        <indexes>
            <index ordered="true">__key.eventType</index>
        </indexes>
```

As a `key-value` store, it's usual to search on the values, so that's what the index expects. When you put `eventType` in the index it looks for that field in
the value. You need to change it to `__key.eventType` to make it look in the key.

If you need frequent search access to part of a composite primary key, as the index implements, then the choice of primary key structure may need reviewed.

Also, if you can, upgrade from 3.11.2 to 3.12.1. There are some querying improvements behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this approach and Hazelcast started using indexes. But I noticed overall performance degradation due frequent inserts and deletes in the hazelcast IMap. 

Briefly my usecase: I need to insert almost 10K records per sec in IMap ttl eviction is set to 30 sec using LRU policy.  

Finally ditched the idea of using indexes.

Comment: That's more of a design question, perhaps not appropriate for this forum as it's about problems. Or at the very least a separate question.